# IE8 Favicon Issues

Tags: internet-explorer-8, favicon

So, I have been asked to fix an issue where a favicon isn't appearing in IE8 at work, but can't seem to figure out why it isn't working.  I've even read the official Microsoft documentation on the subject, but haven't managed to get anywhere with this.

I have included the following in head of the site template, where $sitebase is set to http://www.slinkynote.com/ in the config file.  The favicon image is a 32px by 32px .ico file.

```
<link href="<?php echo $site_base;?>favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link href="<?php echo $site_base;?>favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
```

Does anyone have any experience with this issue?  It appears fine in FF and Chrome.

Thanks,

Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PNG image in ICO file, and setting wrong mime type. Make another icon but **ACTUAL** icon file and put it in the place of current one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that IE8 caches the icon in the browsing history (and NOT its temporary Internet files) ... if it fails once in IE, it will not try again for a while (I don't know how long, but long enough to be very annoying) ... anyway, the following simple header links work fine:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/icon" href="/favicon.ico">

<link rel="icon" type="image/icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

I'm not sure why you need them both, probably cross-browser compatibility. But the href does NOT need a hostname with `www` in it, or any hostname at all. It works even on a local machine

However, if IE8 has messed up its cache then this will drive you crazy. Luckily the solution is simple: change the links to the following (just add x) and make sure the icon will load first time (or else you will just mess up the cache again) ...

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/icon" href="/xfavicon.ico">

<link rel="icon" type="image/icon" href="/xfavicon.ico">
```

Afterwards change the links back to what you wanted originally,  then the icon will reload the next time and thereafter be cached successfully.